# Perl exit on warning

Tags: perl, warnings

I'd like a Perl script to exit with an error code immediately on any kind of warning.  For example, on an "argument ... isn't numeric in addition" warning.

How can one do this?

Comment: you may catch the warning as follows:
`perl -w -mstrict -e '$SIG{__WARN__} = sub{ die "died because: ",@_; }; print "foo" + 2;`
this prints
`died because: Argument "foo" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.`
to stderr and exits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html#Fatal-Warnings) pragma has the FATAL option:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
```

Comment: Note that new warnings may be introduced in future versions of Perl. Avoid `FATAL => 'all'` in code that needs to be futureproof.

Comment: Thank you, that did it absolutely! 
@duskwuff : this is a paranoid script, so its suitable for this use-case.

Answer (score 4):

toolic's answer of `use warnings FATAL => 'all';` is correct, but there are some caveats. There are some warnings emitted by internal perl functions that really don't expect to be dying. There's a list of those unsafe-to-fatalize warnings in [`perldoc strictures`](https://metacpan.org/pod/strictures).

As of version 2.000003 of `strictures`, it enables warnings as follows:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use warnings NONFATAL => qw(
  exec
  recursion
  internal
  malloc
  newline
  experimental
  deprecated
  portable
);
no warnings 'once';
```

See https://metacpan.org/pod/strictures#CATEGORY-SELECTIONS for the full rationale.

Instead of copy/pasting the above lines into your code, you could of course just

```
use strictures 2;
```

which also enables `strict` for you.
(You might have to install `strictures` first, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Not mentioned yet, but you can set a `__WARN__` handler and do what you like there.

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    die "This program does not tolerate warnings like: @_";        
};
```